# Installation aborted when trying to adb sideload to Nexus 7 for upgrading to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-7, android-versions

I have a Nexus 7 2012 device and I am attempting to upgrade to lollipop.  I can get the right image from:

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

However, when I try to upgrade from 4.4.2, I run the command:

`adb sideload lollipop.zip`

The file gets uploaded, but the device then says:

`Verifing the update package:
E: Footer is wrong
E. Signature Verification Failed
Installation aborted.`

I tried both images for the 2012 Wifi and Mobile versions, same result. I also tried to do a factory reset.

Are the images wrong, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The factory images provided on that page are not packaged for installation via Android's recovery system. You'll need to use [the flashing instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#instructions) to install the images using `fastboot`. If your device's bootloader is not unlocked already, this would require wiping all of your data. If it is unlocked, then you can skip the wipe by flashing just the bootloader upgrade, the the system image, and the boot image:

```
fastboot flash bootloader
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash boot /path/to/boot.img
fastboot flash system /path/to/system.img
```

The alternative would be to incrementally apply the OTA updates for your device up to the latest version. These *are* designed to work in recovery mode, but need to be applied in order from earliest to latest since they are patch updates, not full system images. The Nexus 7 Wi-Fi OTA updates can be obtained from Google's servers using the following links:

- [KOT49H (4.4.2) to KTU84L (4.4.3)](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/ce921efc1fa9197e9b336ce3f89cbfa2275ea4bb.signed-nakasi-KTU84L-from-KOT49H.ce921efc.zip)
- [KTU84L to KTU84P (4.4.4)](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/81f4eaa244e9b90ecc98edbb51108c85fa128f2b.signed-nakasi-KTU84P-from-KTU84L.81f4eaa2.zip)
- [KTU84P to LRX21P (5.0)](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/4939a9ff6d10c495beaed26ac96228246f724272.signed-nakasi-LRX21P-from-KTU84P.4939a9ff.zip)
- [LRX21P to LRX22G (5.0.2)](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/a6645eee89af34f58db74f6a1ad93fe400fcfc7b.signed-nakasi-LRX22G-from-LRX21P.a6645eee.zip)
- [LRX22G to LMY47D (5.1)](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/9f163586073265c54d86679efd63513a4477cfd8.signed-nakasi-LMY47D-from-LRX22G.9f163586.zip)

For the GSM-enabled version, you can use these links:

- [KOT49H to KTU84L](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasig/21863855a5d1e8960003f841347313feab3c665b.signed-nakasig-KTU84L-from-KOT49H.21863855.zip)
- [KTU84L to KTU84P](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasi/81f4eaa244e9b90ecc98edbb51108c85fa128f2b.signed-nakasi-KTU84P-from-KTU84L.81f4eaa2.zip)
- [KTU84P to LRX22G](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_nakasig/4f3f0971f71ad7aa14dcbebe0dae3af2b599c269.signed-nakasig-LRX22G-from-KTU84P.4f3f09711.zip)
- The 2012 Nexus 7 GSM has not received a 5.1 OTA yet. You must currently use the factory images if you want to update to 5.1.

Additional OTA links can be found in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1745781), if needed.

Comment: It seems I was not using the OTA files, but the factory images.  I found one for the WifI version, but I am looking for the mobile version.

Comment: @KristyWelsh The GSM model of the N7 hasn't received an OTA to 5.1 yet, but I've added links that will get you up to 5.0.2. If you want to install 5.1 you'll have to use fastboot to flash the factory image for now.

Comment: I would just like any version of lollipop to be installed.

Comment: Sideloading the three updates in the second set from top to bottom would put you on Lollipop (5.0.2).

Comment: I get a failure in doing the first package: Failed to verify the whole-file signature When starting with the first one.

Comment: Are you on KOT49H currently? You should be able to find that in Settings => About device, I think. Aside from that, usually a corrupted download will give a signature error like that. You could try re-downloading it, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is defintely working for me. following the steps in sequence

- Install ADB and boot loader from following link to PC
  http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-install-adb-and-fastboot-with-drivers-on-windows-quickest-setup/
- The alternative would be to incrementally apply the OTA updates for your device up to the latest version. These are designed to work in recovery mode, but need to be applied in order from earliest to latest since they are patch updates, not full system images. The Nexus 7 Wi-Fi OTA updates can be obtained from Google's servers using the following links:

KOT49H (4.4.2) to KTU84L (4.4.3)
KTU84L to KTU84P (4.4.4)
KTU84P to LRX21P (5.0)
LRX21P to LRX22G (5.0.2)
LRX22G to LMY47D (5.1)